# Android loopj asynchttpclient return response

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, android-asynctask, loopj

In one of my project, I am using `loopj asynchttpclient` for communicating with my website. 
The communication part working well and getting response as well

My activity looks like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        WebRequest test=new WebRequest();
        test.callService();
}
```

WebRequest Class as

```
public class WebRequest extends Activity {


    public void callService(){


        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post("http://domain.com/dp/index.php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                Log.v("P",response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
                 Log.v("PS",e.toString());
            }

    });
    }




}
```

I am confused how to return the response to the main activity, So that I can create the listview from that response.

I am new to this
Please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### In your WebRequest class:

- I don't think you want this class to extend `Activity`. You should only extend `Activity` when you're making a page to display in your app. You just want to execute some code, so extending `Activity` isn't needed.
- Change your call service method to be static and take an `AsyncHttpClient` as a parameter.

Your `WebRequest` class should now look like this:

```or-tag-here
final class WebRequest {
    private AsyncHttpClient mClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    public static void callService(AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler) {
        mClient.post("http://domain.com/dp/index.php", handler);
    }
}
```

### In your main Activity:

Now all you have to do in your main activity is call the static method like this:

```or-tag-here
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        WebRequest.callService(new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // Initiated the request
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                // Successfully got a response
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
                // Response failed :(
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // Completed the request (either success or failure)
            }
        });
}
```

Do whatever you need to do with the Views in your activity in the above callbacks. Hope this Helps!

Comment: Okey thanks for the comment. So as you said, I need to repeat the code onStart, onSuccess, onFailure, onFilish all in my activity where ever I want to call the webservice. right ? Suppose in a page if I need 2-3 calls I wanna repeat the above code twice or thrice. is it ?

Comment: Correct. I also will add that you don't have to implement all of the callback methods, only the ones that you need. Often times I only implement onSuccess() and onFailure(). Hope this helps and good luck! If my answer helped you I'd appreciate if you checked it as the correct answer. Thanks!